# How to play raw data with gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, gst-launch, gst-launch-1.0

I want to play `/dev/urandom` using `gst-launch-1.0`, just as I can do it with `aplay`:

```
aplay /dev/urandom
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a quick start try using this:

`gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/dev/urandom ! rawaudioparse ! alsasink`

Of course you modify it to select a specific ALSA device, channel count, sample rate etc..